# .htaccess Mod Rewrite code?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have searched for this but nobody have the same issue..

Now I need an code to transform the ugly url (thats what i have) to the nice url:

- Ugly url: domain.com/aanmelden?referral=admin
- Nice url: domain.com/aanmelden/admin

Ik have tried soo many codes, but no one did work for me. ):

suggestions?
Thnx!

(My current htaccess: )

```
ErrorDocument 401 /errordocs/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errordocs/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errordocs/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

Where and what i need to place?

**EDIT:**

To be clear:

- If the user goes to the Nice Url, they wil stay on the nice one.
- If the user goes to the Ugly Url, they wil redirect to the Nice url.

Comment: Please try to improve your question, it is not clear, wheter you want to rewrite the nice to the ugly url or vice versa.

Comment: The 'ugly url' is the url that i have now, i want this to change to the 'nice url'.

Comment: This means, that mod_rewrite should change the nice url to the ugly url? Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trivial rewrite:

If `admin` can be any lowercase string, use the pattern `([a-z]+)$` to capture one or more lowercase letters after the `/` and before the end of the request URI.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aanmelden/([a-z]+)$ aanmelden?referral=$1 [L]
```

If `admin` is really only `admin`, you can hard-code it as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aanmelden/admin aanmelden?referral=admin [L]
```

#### Update

In context of your existing rewrites just posted, you'll need to add this rule before the rule that adds .php since that would also match this pattern.

```
# Do this before the rule that adds .php
# Also added condition so this doesn't apply to real files...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^aanmelden/([a-z]+)$ aanmelden?referral=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

#### Update 2

If you want the end user to get the ugly URL and rewrite it to the nice one, use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_QUERYSTRING} referral=([a-z]+)
RewriteRule ^aanmelden aanmelden/%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! i understand all what you did exept for the [L] at the end. What does that mean? Im gonna try this now.

Comment: @user1303265 The `[L]` means this is the "last" processing to be done for this match, and that no further rewrite rules that match the pattern should be handled.  You'll usually want the `[L]`, and in your case if you have no other rules it isn't needed, but will protect you if you from unexpected results if you add more rules later

Comment: Hmm.. it didnt work for me ):

See my edited start post for my current htaccess..

Comment: @user1303265 See above. It needs to go before the rule that appends .php

Comment: hmm.. it dont works? The page domain.nl/aanmelden/admin is not found, and domain.nl/aanmelden?referral=admin dont redirect to the right url? Can you post the full httaccess (that I need) in your post above? Thanks! (:

Comment: @user1303265 To see whether it is being matched, change `[L]` to `[L,R=301]` to force it to redirect. You'll be able to see what url it ends up on

Comment: now the "domain.nl/aanmelden/admin" exist! but it redirect to the "domain.nl/aanmelden?refferal=admin"... (Need to redirect the opposite. ):

Comment: @user1303265 That's the opposite of what rewrite rules are usually used for.  Typically your end user enters the pretty URL, which is internally redirected to the ugly one.  I'll edit above.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough.. The url must *stay* on the pretty url, but if the go to the ugly url, it will redirect them to the pretty one. (see the edit in my first post for an example)